Texworks: changing window between several opened files does not work
Texworks Version 0.6.9 ("Arch Linux") on EndeavourOS.
When several files are open, we must be able to change the active file by clicking Window in the Menu and select the window that we wish, however, that does not work.
This was working in previous versions, running on Debian. How should I activate this function? I mean how to change focus on the active window.
Thank you for your hints.
Hamid

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
